# Get value at column using SPSS Python Script

Tags: python, scripting, spss

I have an SPSS Python script that iterates through a table and reads in each row of values for a specific columns and sets the parameter values accordingly.  Currently, I'm accessing the values with getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).  However, having to refer to column index, as opposed to column name, is not ideal as table columns may shift.  Is there a way to refer to values based on column name?

**Sample code**

```
diagram = modeler.script.diagram()

for i in range(nrows):

    jobid = job_rowset.getValueAt(i, 0);
    city = job_rowset.getValueAt(i, 3);
    country = job_rowset.getValueAt(i, 4);

    diagram.setParameterValue ('BU', bu)
    diagram.setParameterValue ('City_Param', city)
    diagram.setParameterValue ('CountryID_Param', country)
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the first row will contain the names, (or that you have something available that specifies the column order), you can construct a dictionary with the Column names as keys and the column numbers values.

This would give something like:

```
name_key_dict = dict()
for i in range(ncols):
    name_key_dict[colnames[i]] = i # Assuming that names is the ordered list of columns
# I would add a check here that you have the required columns

param_col_list = [ # This constructs a list of parameters vs column numbers
    ('BU', name_key_dict.get('Bu_Col')),
    ('City_Param', name_key_dict.get('City')), 
    ('CountryID_Param', name_key_dict.get('Country Code')), 
]
for row in job_rowset: # Assuming job_rowset is an iterable with a member of getValue
    for (param, col) in param_col_list:
        diagram.setParameterValue(param, row.getValue(col))
```

Comment: Thanks!  The suggestion worked with a few minor tweaks in creating the name_key_dict and in the iteration at the end.